# How can I autoclean my gnome main menu?

Tags: gnome, cleanup

I like to experiment with lots of different software in my Ubuntu install. Then, every time Ubuntu reaches a new release cycle, I simply do a clean install (instead of upgrading) to get rid of all the extra software (and their respective config files/folders). The only thing I always backup and carry to the next install (besides personal files) are the config files for gnome, so my desktop is always the way I like it. =)

The problem with that, is that the different packages I test out never get properly uninstalled, so my gnome main menu is full of broken links referring to software I had in previous installations (which got carried over because I kept the gnome config files).

**Is there any automated way to go through my gnome main menu and remove any broken links?** I know how to manually edit the menu, and I could go through it myself, but I'm looking for some script or package that will clean for me so I wouldn't have to do it manually every release cycle.

Comment: I guess that people do not read the question before answering.
Not a single answer in the topic ...
BTW, did you find a good solution since then ?

Comment: @RaphaelJolivet No, but I stopped using ubuntu shortly after asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found this script

```
export PACKAGES=$(dpkg -l | awk '{if ($1 == "rc") print $2" "}' | tr -d '\n') [ -n "$PACKAGES" ] && sudo apt-get purge $PACKAGES
```

on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=857034) that shall purge the removed installations. So maybe it could work also for purging menu.

Answer (score 1):

To really-really-really :P reset your Gnome menu enter this command:

```
rm -rf .local/share/applications/*
```

I came across [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alacarte/+bug/118936) in 2008, and I don't know if it's being fixed, BTW it's annoying.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

this one worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Open **Synaptic** and select from the left menu under *All/Installed/ect.* **not installed (residual config)**

Comment: are you sure this works for such situations?